# CSS bleed over, despite height set to auto with nested divs

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to get a simple skeleton formed for a web page, and I'm having trouble with my divs lining up. For some reason I have nested divs bleeding outside of their parent divs, even though I have the parent divs' height set to auto.

Here is the markup I have set out:

```
    <h1><center>Title</center></h1>

    <div class="main">
        <nav>
            <div class="button">
                Link 1
            </div>                  
            <div class="button">
                Link 2
            </div>
            <div class="button">
                Link 3
            </div>
        </nav>
        <br/>
        <br/>

        <div class="mainPic">

        </div>

        <div class="sideText">

        </div>

        <p>
            Main text.
        </p>
    </div>
```

and here is the CSS I have modifying the divs:

```
div.main {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 75%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 20px;
}

nav {
    border: 1px dashed black;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

div.button {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 2px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;

}

div.mainPic {
    border: double black;
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
}

div.sideText {
    border: dotted black;
    width: 30%;
    float: right;
    height: 50px
}
```

My problems are:
1) The nav acts like it has nothing inside it (the dashed line), even though I have my button classes nested within it.
2) My "mainPic" (double solid line) div flows outside of my "main" div, even though the height on main is set to auto. Same goes for the right side inner panel (dotted line). 
3) I want my main text block to appear below the two inner boxes, yet it shows up between them.

How do I fix these?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the following

```
nav, div.main {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

this will cause the floating contents of `nav` and `div.main` to remain *inside* their respective parents.

---

**edit**

It has been pointed out that the `position: relative;` is probably not necessary in modern browsers.  Therefore, the following should work just as well:

```
nav, div.main {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here's a link to the part of the CSS Spec that discusses [flow root](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#flow-root).  Setting `overflow:hidden` establishes a box as a "flow root", and the spec defines [special rules for computing the height of an element that is a "flow root"](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#root-height).

Comment: Perfect! It works just fine without the relative position attribute. Should I still add it and why?

Comment: The `position:relative` used to be necessary (long ago).  Back then, there was this notion of "positioning context" -- floated elements were not automatically placed along the edge of their immediate parent, instead they were placed at the edge of the closest containing *positioning context*.  Positioning context was established by virtue of being either relative or absolute positioned.  The relative position on the parent div was therefore necessary.  I still include it out of habit (and for safe measure), but it is probably no longer needed anything resembling a modern browser.

Comment: @mu, actually, if you say "clearfix" to anyone who has been around since the early days of CSS-P [*this*](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html) is what they'll think you're referring to.  "Clearfix" is an old solution that hacks around bugs in older browsers. It's is a hacky mess, and really should no longer be used.  The method I've outlined above is one of the methods defined in the CSS spec, that will establish a block as a [flow root](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#flow-root).  It is this concept of "flow root" that requires the box to expand to fully enclose its floated children.

Answer (score 3):

Add a div for clearing your float to your html file:

```
<div class="mainPic"></div>
<div class="sideText"></div>
<div class="clear" />
<p>Main text.</p>
```

Css

```
.clear { clear: both; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `overflow:hidden` to any parent element that contains a floated child. This will clear the floated elements without having to add extra DIVs.

Note, for IE to act the same as other browsers, add `zoom:1;` to go with `overflow:hidden`. This will add *hasLayout* for IE6.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a spacing element with `clear: both` after the floating elements.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the nested `div`s are `float`ed. If you need the `float`, add `float: left;` for the `main div` also.

Answer (score 0):

1) The `<nav>` is collapsed because you are floating the buttons.  Instead try `display: inline` or `display: inline-block` for the buttons.

2, 3)  Float is the culprit here as well.  Clear the float on your `<p>` element:

```
p {
    clear: left;
}
```

Or don't float `div.mainPic` at all.  Since you already have `.sideText` floating right, that should be good enough.  You would have to move the `.sideText` ahead of `div.mainPic` in the html.

By the way, since you are already using HTML5 with `<nav>`, perhaps it would be appropriate to use [`<aside>`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html#the-aside-element) instead of `<div class="sideText">`.